# How do you group things in Trello (like scenarios under a feature)?

Tags: trello

We are trying to use Trello for our development process. We can't seem to find a nice way to group things in Trello. What would be nice is something like a "stack" of cards so that we can have a Feature stack and each card would be a Story/Scenario. Maybe some other way to link cards together would be nice (when lists are used for the process itself).

We tried having things in description but you can't copy paste formatted text in there. Tried in a checklist, same problem. We could have a whole new list per feature but I am not sure how well that will work, especially with the whole next up/in progress/review/etc workflow.

I was wondering if anybody is using Trello for Agile, how do you group things?

Comment: What kind of formatted text do you need?

Answer (score 5):

There are only up to 5 or 6 lists that can be viewable at the same time.

So the two options would be to use:

- A Card as the feature and the description for user stories
- A List as the feature and Card for user stories

In the first option I would imagine it would have to be something like

[image: My yard always needs cleaning]

Here you would need to add up the points manually (Or create a userscript/extenstion see next option).

In the second option you can use [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdbcdblgjdpmfninkoogcfpnkjmndgje) to take care of your user points and let cards handle user stories. As you said this can be come unmanageable with next up/in progress/review/ so then you would have to keep the tracking cards to the left and the feature to the right on your board. When a new activity appears on a board ensure it is "bubbled" to the left as the most recent feature update. Assigning members can also ensure nothing is forgotten.

[image: The door is always jammed]

Answer (score 1):

[Hello Epics](https://helloepics.com) seem to do be able to group cards as children of a parent card. I use it to group Tasks under a User Story, and User Stories under an Epic. It comes with a 30-day trial, then you'll have to pay for it. Please see if this works for you.

[image]

Comment: _similar thing_ what are the thing? Please include essential parts of the link into answer to make it clear.